# SQL Server : output inserted value as well as value from SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-insert

I would like to insert into a `TempTable` the inserted column value, which I have working, as well as a column from the original select all in one shot. Is this possible?

This works where `a` is the PK that is auto-generated and `b` and `c` are other columns.

```
INSERT INTO App.Table1 (b, c)
OUTPUT inserted.a INTO #TempTable
    SELECT b, c
    FROM App.Table2
```

Can I do something like:

```
INSERT INTO App.Table1 (b, c)
OUTPUT t2.a, inserted.a INTO #TempTable
    SELECT b, c, a
    FROM App.Table2 t2
```

Effectively I want a `#TempTable` that has the original PK of the row and the new PK so I have a lookup table essentially.

Comment: *"Is this possible?"* no. The `OUTPUT` clause can only return values from the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented by Larnu, `OUTPUT` can not refer to columns coming from the `SELECT` part of the `INSERT`.

You could work around this with a `MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE INTO App.Table1
USING App.Table2 AS t2
ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT((b, c)) Values(t2.b, t2.c)
OUTPUT inserted.a, t2.a INTO #TempTable
```

Answer (score 3):

*"Is this possible?"* No. The `OUTPUT` clause can only return details of rows effected in the DML statement (those inserted in this case).

This can *easily* be tested with the below batch:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable1 (ID int IDENTITY,
                           SomeString varchar(10));

CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable2 (ID int IDENTITY,
                           SomeString varchar(10));

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable1 (SomeString)
VALUES('abc'),('def');

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable2 (SomeString)
OUTPUT MT1.ID, inserted.ID
SELECT MT1.ID
FROM dbo.MyTable1 MT1
ORDER BY MT1.ID DESC;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable1;
DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable2;
```

This will result in the below error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
>   The multi-part identifier "MT1.ID" could not be bound.

This is also implied from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Returns information from, or expressions based on, **each row affected** by an INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement.

Emphasis added. A row from the source table (`dbo.MyTable1.ID` is this case) isn't affected by the INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement, so is inaccessible from the `OUTPUT` clause.

*Edit: GMB has added a nice work around, however, using `MERGE`, as the rows are affected by the `MERGE` statement and thus accessible from the `OUTPUT` clause.*